# Is there any reason why this Workflow will not trigger?

Tags: workflow

Why does my Workflow return false when it appears to hit the correct condition?  I have included the WF formula and redacted log output below.

```
AND(CONTAINS($Setup.Email_Offices__c.Offices__c , Project__r.Office__r.Name ), 
     Complete__c != null)


12:26:43:170 WF_FORMULA Formula:ENCODED:[treatNullAsNull]AND(CONTAINS({!ID:$Setup.xxxxx} , {!ID:xxxxxx.xxxxxxx.Name} ),
12:26:42:000 WF_FORMULA {!ID:xxxxxxxx} != null)|
                         Values:$Setup.Email_Offices__c.Offices__c=XYZ, 
                         Complete__c=2015-02-27 17:26:00,
                         Project__r.Office__r.Name=XYZ
12:26:43:170 WF_CRITERIA_END false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up working when I used `NOT(ISNULL(CAD_QA_Complete__c))` instead of `Complete__c != null`.  Looks like Dates don't do well in `!=` operators.

Answer (score 1):

Is your workflow set to run anytime the conditions are met, or only when the conditions are "subsequently met"? I'm not sure, but the latter could cause this to fail even when the record meets the criteria, as it appears to above.

Barring that, I would try to debug this by removing one of the conditions from the workflow and firing it again, then seeing if it still evaluates to false. Maybe you can isolate the problematic condition.